# show wp comment as rejected to all users

Tags: wordpress, comments

I would like to be able to "reject" a comment in wp's backend without altering or deleting the comments contents.

On the front end of the website I would like have the comment authors name listed as normal but instead of the comments contents have a simple statement that reads "This comment was rejected for violations of our TOS"

How would I go about this? There doesnt seem to be a plugin that I have found to handle this function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code snippet. This snippet will filters the text of a comment to be displayed.

```
function filter_text( $comment_text, $comment = null ) {
    // Do something to the comment, possibly switching based on the presence of $comment
    $comment_text = 'This comment was rejected for violations of our TOS';
    return $comment_text;
}
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'filter_text', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: that looks good, now the question is, how do I add a function to function.php to input a link next to "approve" under the comments page so that I can flag it as "rejected" and have this function you suggested applied.